# How to place image button to extreme right?

Tags: android, imageview

I have horinzontal linear layout which contans one TextView and one ImageView. The length of text is not fix and I want to place the Image to the extreme right.
I tried `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`
then `android:layout_marginRight="0dip"`
but nothing works properly.
please Help..!!

Comment: why don't you use RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 4):

You can set `android:layout_weight="1"` in `TextView` no need to write `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

example

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icn_listarrow" />
```